# How to upload image or file in react js?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I want to upload image / file in a react project, but dont want to use formdata to post, instead i want to use body for the post method through Axios.
If I can convert my file into **base 64**, I think i will be able to post the image through body.
Can anyone tell me solution how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```js
function encodeImageFileAsURL(element) {
  var file = element.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = function() {
    console.log('RESULT', reader.result)
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

Comment: thanks, But what to pass in the body while posting.

Comment: set this header: `Content-Type : image/jpeg` , `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64`